# Updating SQL Table to match with another value

Tags: php, mysql

When using SQL with PHP I need to figure out how to add a value to the same row as an existing value. For example:

```
 Amount             ASIN                SalesRank
 ________________________________________________
 Needed Value1  ||  Value1      ||       32135
 Needed Value2  ||  Value2      ||       65421
```

I would have the ASIN value, and need to insert an Amount Value. How would I go about inserting the value into the correct row?

The current error I am getting :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in FilePath on line 149
```

Line 149 =

```
$asinXml = simplexml_load_file(xmlFile);
foreach($asinXml->GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult as $asinItem)
```

Comment: You mean update your Amount column? use primary key.

Comment: The rows are not in that order. Can you answer with some example php code?

Comment: Use this sql statement : "UPDATE `<TableName>`
SET Amount=`<AmountValue>` WHERE ASIN=`<query parameter>`''

Comment: In order to update the value of a particular field, you will need to search that field either by matching `ASIN` or by matching `SalesRank` value, either one of these can be the query parameters.

Comment: How would I set it? I would like to search the table by asin and update the amount with a value.

Comment: Let's say you search for the field with ASIN = 123,then you would write it as : "UPDATE `<TableName>` SET Amount=`<AmountValue>` WHERE ASIN=123" and then run this query using the mysql_query() function in PHP

Comment: Alright. Thanks bud. I appreciate it. I will comment again with any problems.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? Don't use both tags if you're just using one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"UPDATE TABLE_NAME
 SET Amount= NEW_AMOUNT
 WHERE ASIN= EXISTING_ASIN_NUMBER"
```

Replace `TABLE_NAME` with the name of the table.
Replace `NEW_AMOUNT` with the new amount you want to update it with
Replace `EXISTING_ASIN_NUMBER` with the value of that row. Using your example, you can use "Value1" or "Value2"

Example:
Assume table name is `MyTable`

```
 Amount             ASIN                SalesRank
 ________________________________________________
 Needed Value1  ||  Value1      ||       32135
 Needed Value2  ||  Value2      ||       65421

 "UPDATE MyTable
 SET Amount= 'new value'
 WHERE ASIN= 'Value1'"

 Amount             ASIN                SalesRank
 ________________________________________________
 new value      ||  Value1      ||       32135
 Needed Value2  ||  Value2      ||       65421
```

Comment: I will try it out now. Thanks.

Comment: The Amount column did not have any values changed.

Comment: @Robert What result did you get?

Comment: It was an error in my other code. Ill update the question with it, if you are willing to help me?

Comment: Yeah sure, go for it!

Comment: The example code that you supplied did not do anything. I am not sure if i am implementing it correctly or not..

Comment: @Robert The error you posted tells me nothing. What I can advice is, print the content every few lines and see where it is modified or at what point it is changed. Like I don't know what `asinXml` is suppose to be and what it is

Comment: Asin xml is in the for loop. That isn't the problem anyone. I fixed the error. Now, the program will update the mysql db. When I run the command in php my admun, it works. When I run it outside of phpmyadmin, it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Comment: @Robert I am not sure what is causing that issue. Just to be sure, the answer I provided with works, right?

Comment: It did work, after I changed the table creation to have a primary key. When I created the table I didn't have one. Thanks.